# django static files cannot be found

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-settings

In my settings file i have the following

`STATIC_URL = '/static/'`

my app name is reg_service

So my directory structure is like `reg_service/reg_service/settings.py`

And i have the static directory in `reg_service/static/js`
                                    `reg_service/manage.py`
                                   `reg_service/reg_service`
                                   `reg_service/templates`

But in my template if i include the following script the result is `"GET /static/js/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1652` whats is wrong here

```
    <script src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You should be using `{{ load static }}` and `{{ static 'js/jquery.min.js' }}`. I don't think `STATIC_URL` is intended to be used directly.

Comment: When i do the above error is  Could not parse the remainder: ' static' from 'load static'

Comment: actually is {% load staticfiles %}

Comment: I tried with both {% load static %} {% static 'js/jquery.min.js' %} and {% load static %} {{ static 'js/jquery.min.js' }} and its still the same

Comment: @mxlian: Right. `{%` not `{{`. Going from memory, and just woke up.

Comment: i do not have a document_root settings is it fine?

Comment: I think you should start all over again with the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

Comment: Unless you really want to serve your static pages via the Django app server, you should be able to reach your static pages with only your main, non-Django, web server. Figuring out what the static url  actually is should assist you in diagnosing this.

Comment: @Rajeev: Where does the STATIC_ROOT point to?

Comment: I have not used static root.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of django is that you should serve your static files directly through your web server.

For development purposes you can 'trick' django to serve the static files themself:

**urls.py:**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Django will find your static files, and serve them under the url defined under STATIC_URL.

That's not very performant nor secure, but works ok for development. For production you should configure your web server (Apache, Nginx, whatever) to serve the files directly under the url defined in STATIC_URL.

For more information see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development